# Proving that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f = L\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow L=0$ and $f$ has a limit at every point $c\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R},f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Assume that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f = L\in\mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $L = 0$, and then prove that $f$ has a limit at every point $c\in\mathbb{R}$

[Hint: First note
that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},f(2x) = f(x) + f(x) = 2f(x)$. Also note that $\forall x,c\in\mathbb{R}f(x) = f(x - c) + f(c)$]

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

It's routine to prove with $a=f(1)$ that

$$f(x)=ax,\quad \forall x\in\Bbb Q$$
and using the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$ let $(x_n)$ a sequence of elements in $\Bbb Q$ convergent to $0$ so
$$\ell=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} ax_n=0$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, use note that $f(2x) = 2f(x)$ is the same as $f({x \over 2}) = {1 \over 2} f(x)$. So $f({1 \over 2}) = {1 \over 2} f(2)$, $f({1 \over 4}) = {1 \over 2}f({1 \over 2}) = {1 \over 4} f(1)$, and more generally $f({1 \over 2^n}) = {1 \over 2^n} f(1)$. This tells you that $L$ has to be zero.

For the second part, you want to show
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow x} f(y) = f(x)$$
This is the same as 
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow x} (f(y) - f(x)) = 0$$
Which by your second hint is the same as
$$\lim_{y \rightarrow x} f(y - x) = 0$$
This in turn is the same as
$$\lim_{(y-x) \rightarrow 0} f(y - x) = 0$$

But this is exactly part a).